# Dawnguard vampire lord and companions werewolf question

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I have the dawnguard DLC for Skyrim and I want to know what will happen if I become a vampire lord before I start doing the companions quests that eventually turns me into a werewolf.

If I complete dawnguard and chose to be a vampire lord before doing companions werewolf transformation, will I be forced to do the werewolf blessing or can I just skip it?

Also, if I do become a vampire lord, and choose to become a werewolf, will I be able to cure the werewolf disease and become a vampire lord again?